# How to set score in correct sequence (100 being 1st) - (90 being 2nd) - (80 being 3rd)?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Im fixing a word game, and the user should type in the word correctly, but if s/he types it in correctly the 1st time they should receive 100 score, every time they get it wrong there after the score should drop by 10 points...

So far Ive done this:

```
- (IBAction)btncheck:(id)sender {
NSString *answer = [_textbox.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
if([answer isEqualToString:@""]){
}
else    
if ([answer isEqualToString:@"q"]) {
    _keyboard.hidden = YES;
    _textXclear.hidden = YES;
    //Perfect button
    [_closeone setHidden:NO];
    [_wrongone setHidden:YES];
    [_closetwo setHidden:NO];
    score = 100;
    [scoreLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"score: %d", score]];
```

But it only assigns 100 points every time, instead of losing points for every wrong answer!!
would anyone know the solution?

Comment: What with the first part of the `if statement` that's empty???? Is this really needed if you don't do anything???

Comment: Set score to 100 before the loop and decrement by 10 inside the loop...

Comment: @floris how would i do that though?

Comment: look at your code, you are setting score to 100, and then set the label.text to score wich is 100 every time.
where does your code tries to do the "score -= 10;" ?

Comment: @OthmanTazi thats true, how would I fix that?

Comment: score = 100; in an initialisation method.
score = score - 10; when a wrong answer is touched.

Comment: I put my comment in answer, so you can close the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`score = 100;` in an initialisation method. 
`score = score - 10;` when a wrong answer is touched.

Comment: 'if ([answer isEqualToString:@"q"]) {
   
        score = score +100;
        [scoreLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"score: %d", score]];
    }
    else {
        score = score -10;
        [scoreLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"score: %d", score]];
       }'

Answer (score 0):

An incomplete example:

```
Score = 110;
Guess = false;
While(Guess==false && Score > 0){
  Guess=GetNextGuess(); // which sets guess to true if correct
  Score -= 10;
}
// get here when score is zero or
// word was guessed correctly
```

Comment: let me try that one second!